# Invalid conversion error in cv2 file while installing opencv 3.3.0 on Raspberry Pi Stretch

Tags: python, c++, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to build opencv 3.3.0 on raspberry pi 3 but facing an error at 93% saying invalid conversion. Details are provided below any help will be greatly appreciated. please help.

> This error message is showing up.

```
 /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp: In function ‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, T&, const char*) [with T = cv::String; PyObject = _object]’:/home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:854:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive] char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);In file included from /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.c
```

I Tried these commands

> cd ~/opencv-3.3.0/
>
> ```
> $ mkdir build
> $ cd build
> $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
>     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
>     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
>     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules \
>     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
> ```

#cv2.cpp code at error location.

```
template<>
bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, String& value, const char* name)
{
 (void)name;
 if(!obj || obj == Py_None)
    return true;
 char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);
 if(!str)
    return false;
 value = String(str);
 return true;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`; but if you need the CMake compiled version, like for ROS, then it appears to be a bug in OpenCV; after I did the following change at opencv3/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp lin 885, it compiled for me. Change...

`char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);`

to

`const char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);`

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered same phenomenon. It was hard since compile takes much time and I spent more than half day to resolve this.

TLDR:

1) Building opencv is not recommended any more. Give up building from source.

2) Raspberry pie provides opencv wheel. Try this.

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

3) If it doesn't work, simply use apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

4) For python3,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

Please let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. It's true that building opencv on the raspberry pi is not a smart way and there is website www.piwheels.org which provides precompiled packages.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of frustration, I found out that,opencv is actually full of bugs and its not always your fault. I ran Opencv version 4(previously i was trying Opencv 3.3.0) on Raspberry pi stretch and it compiled smoothly without a single error. One more thing is to make sure you have increased your swap space to 2048 before compilation.

> /etc/dphys-swapfile

make it 2048 from 100.

Happy coding..!!